# Yum, OpenSSH and dedicated server over ssh

Tags: ssh, yum, remote, dedicated-server

Quick question:

In `RHEL5.5` there is `OpenSSH 4.3b2` but I really need jailed root functionality (available from 4.8b1 I think). I am working on a dedicated server over ssh. Is it safe to yum remove openssh and then install newer version or will I loose connection once removed openSSH and will be unable to install new version/connect to server at all?

BTW. Can I 'yum' never version or will I have to compile it from the source or something?

Comment: What exactly do you need for the jailed root? Do you need just sftp?

Comment: Define "install new version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that you can `yum update` or `yum upgrade`, you only get security patches in RHEL updates -- very rarely new features.  The current version in RHEL 5 is 4.3p2-72.el5_6.3 which probably doesn't have the chroot features you want.

The good news is that you can build a RPM of the new(er) release that has the feature, then "upgrade" your system to that; yum should leave it alone (however you get to do the security updates yourself in the future).  My notes for doing this for CentOS 5 (which is pretty close to RHEL 5) are at http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/Building+OpenSSH-Portable+for+CentOS

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to `yum upgrade openssh` while the service is running. The installation process should leave the running service alone and loaded into memory, and replace all the files on the filesystem underneath it. The next time you reboot or restart sshd, then it will start up the newer version instead.